# MySQL Database multiple staging environments

Tags: mysql, database, staging

I have this situation, which requires multiple staging environment (unlimited, with unlimited branches).
The basic idea is some how similar to *GIT*.

Let's say I have a `master` database (Production server for example), and I want to create a duplicate of the database, to a new database, where I'll have a staging environment for my development & tests.

In this staging environment I should be able to test new code, bug fixes and everything a developer would like to do, including DB structure and data changes.

I figured how to do this for the data structure (schema) by just dumping the databases structure, and `diff` between them. It work, and I can find the delta's to apply later on the `master` branch. But what about data?

Let's say I have this database:

**master**

```
Table1
ID    name    timestamp
1     row1    2015-08-25 00:00:00
2     row2    2015-08-26 00:00:00
3     row3    2015-08-27 00:00:00
4     row4    2015-08-28 00:00:00

Table1_Table2
table1_id    table2_id
1            1
1            2
2            2
3            3
4            4

Table2
ID    name    timestamp
1     row1    2015-08-25 12:00:00
2     row2    2015-08-27 12:00:00
3     row3    2015-08-26 12:00:00
4     row4    2015-08-28 12:00:00
```

After cloning the DB to a new environment, let's say I did some changes and the clone looks like this:

**clone 1**

```
Table1
ID    name    timestamp
3     row3    2015-08-27 00:00:00
4     row4    2015-08-28 00:00:00
5     row5    2015-08-28 01:00:00

Table1_Table2
table1_id    table2_id
3            3
4            2
5            1

Table2
ID    name    timestamp
1     row1    2015-08-25 12:00:00
2     row2    2015-08-27 12:00:00
3     row3    2015-08-26 12:00:00
```

**The diff between the databases**

```
Table1
 ID    name    timestamp
-1     row1    2015-08-25 00:00:00
-2     row2    2015-08-26 00:00:00
+5     row5    2015-08-28 01:00:00

Table1_Table2
 table1_id    table2_id
-1            1
-1            2
-2            2
-4            4 (This and the one below it, it's actually an update)
+4            2
+5            1

Table2
 ID    name    timestamp
-4     row4    2015-08-28 12:00:00
```

This is great and all, but what like in GIT, the `master` branch may keep it forward, and new data may come and changes may apply.

So here is the `master` some time after replication for the moment I want to merge between `clone1` and `master`

**master**

```
Table1
ID    name    timestamp
1     row1    2015-08-25 00:00:00
2     row2    2015-08-26 00:00:00
3     row3    2015-08-27 00:00:00
4     row4    2015-08-28 00:00:00
5     row5new 2015-08-28 00:00:00

Table1_Table2
table1_id    table2_id
1            1
1            2
2            2
3            3
4            4
5            2

Table2
ID    name    timestamp
1     row1    2015-08-25 12:00:00
2     row2    2015-08-27 12:00:00
3     row3    2015-08-26 12:00:00
4     row4    2015-08-28 12:00:00
```

The diff between `master` *before* replication and *after*:

```
Table1
 ID    name    timestamp
+5     row5new 2015-08-28 00:00:00

Table1_Table2
 table1_id    table2_id
+5            2
```

Now this is an easy one, I didn't do almost any changes at all, but as you can see I have a conflict already. `Table1` row number 5 exists on `clone1` and on `master`, but didn't exists when the replication occurred. This means the user should decide which one he wants to keep.

Unlike GIT, he may want them both. so I should shift the indexes? That may be a bad idea. Because let's say There is another table where the index for the row from master after replication is mentioned, so I should search for it, and update to the new index? This may work, but only if we have relationship between them / we know the business logic, which on both cases may be not at all.

Another issue is that we may want another clone `clone2` that was created after `clone1` and may have different starting points, both in structure and data.

If I'll want to merge between `clone2` and `master` and later merge between `clone1` and `master`, this may resolve in various situation that are pretty hard to predict.

How this can be achieved? I probably missed a couple of issues, but the above are the main that I am facing.

Thanks.

Comment: could you start simpler with as little to read as possible. We have attention spans of flies

Comment: The situation is pretty complex, I can't see how this could be simpler. If you have ideas, you can edit it.